# Comparing 2 different rows in 2 different sheets - Excel

Tags: excel

I am wondering is there is any formula/tool to compare 2 different rows in 2 different sheets in excel.

Example:

Sheet 1 I want to compare cells A14 to A24

with Sheet 2 Cells B14 to B24

Thanks.

Comment: use "=--(Sheet1!A1&Sheet1!B1&Sheet1!C1 = Sheet2!A1&Sheet2!B1&Sheet2!C1)" to generate the results as 0's and 1's instead of Boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
=Sheet1!A1&Sheet1!B1&Sheet1!C1 = Sheet2!A1&Sheet2!B1&Sheet2!C1
```

This basically just compares the concatenation of 3 cells with 3 other cells. But as Zombian said, we could help more if you were more specific.

Comment: Basically I have the same data in two sheets but it is generated at different times. I am trying to see if data changed from one sheet to the second. The location of the cells varies between the two sheets so I would need that in the formula so I can specify which rows/cells to compare

Comment: Can you update your question to include this info along with an example? Don't forget to tag it with your version of Excel.  You can also upload screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of data are you expecting in the cells?
What is the overall goal?  If you are running a test to see if they are exactly the same then it may be different than to see if they all add up to the same number or something like that.

Comment: I am trying to match data from sheet 1 and sheet 2. If there is a variance I would like it indicated ideally.

Comment: If you are just validating the data I recommend using conditional formating.
On Sheet1 choose format only cells that contain 
='[Sheet2.xlsm]Start Page'!B14:B24
And apply the rule to cells A14:A24

Comment: My problem is that I am comparing multiple rows and they are all on different rows in each sheet. Basically I need to specify compare these rows in sheet 1 against these corresponding rows in sheet 2

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your data looks like this way:

On Sheet1 (old data)

```
Col A   |    Col B
Id      |    Value
1       |    My Val 1
2       |    My Val 2
3       |    My Val 3
```

On Sheet2 (new data)

```
Col A   |    Col B
Id      |    Value
123     |    My Val 1
3       |    My new Val 3
2       |    My Val 2
1       |    My new Val 1
```

On Sheet2, put in column C the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))=Sheet2!B2
```

This will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` whether the value matches or not the old one. We need to assume the `Id` would not change between the two Sheets (or else, please tell us how we could deal with it).

Answer (score 0):

... and =INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))=Sheet2!B2
 can be adapted for use in conditional formatting across all the required columns in the second worksheet